# Swift: "mapView.showUserLocation = true" returns "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) "

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

So I'm trying to search for local businesses in Swift using keywords like "bar", or "pizza". I linked the search to a button action so that the locations will pop up on the map within a defined region. However, I can't even get the application to load with user location because I get a nil error.

Here's my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

And here's my ViewController.swift:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

@IBAction func searchBars(sender: AnyObject) {
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Bar"
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occurred in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")

            for item in response.mapItems as [MKMapItem] {
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")
            }
        }
        })

}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
    mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func zoomIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let userLocation = mapView.userLocation

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

The line that returns the nil error is in my ViewController.swift file under @IBAction func zoomIn with the line: let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000). Which gives a nil value for some reason.

Comment: You didn't allocated `weak var mapView: MKMapView!`. If you want it to connect to outlet, you probably didn't did that.

Comment: so i have to connect it to an outlet? i'm having trouble understanding your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with this line is creating a mapView object which is not instantiated yet.

```
weak var mapView: MKMapView!
```

You get the error because you are trying to change `showsUserLocation` property to an object which doesn't exist yet, it's nil.

What you need to do, if you created the map in a storyboard, is to remove the weak var line and put a `IBOutlet` instead (Ctrl + Click and drag from the storyboard).

Comment: Okay so that cleared the error. But now I'm getting another nil value. I feel like techotopia code is really badly explained.
My next nil value is at :

     @IBAction func zoomIn(sender: AnyObject) {
        let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

Comment: Yeah. Techotopia is crap. Can you update your code and the new error you're getting?

Comment: Code is updated!
Okay so I just figured out that I have to -> Play my app -> Come back to XCode -> Debug -> Simulate Location -> Choose a location. And then it will show the location dot. So that problem is solved.

However (I hate that Enter saves the comment...) my Zoom button doesn't work and when I pick my button to search locations nearby, it doesn't show any results. 

Ultimately, my goal is to not show the search results at all, and to just store 5 of them into a table. However, for now I want to make sure I have the fundamentals of MapKit down, which I clearly don't lol.

Comment: Okay I updated code. I'm getting an error when I try to set the region on Zoom In.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Skoua for his help. I figured out what was wrong on my own after he helped me with the IBOutlet.

Here's the corrected code.

```
@IBAction func searchBars(sender: AnyObject) {
    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "bar"
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occurred in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")
//This is where the problem occured
        } else {
            println("Matches found")
        //I needed to insert an else statement for matches being found
            for item in response.mapItems as [MKMapItem] {
                //This prints the 'matches' into [MKMapItem]
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                println("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
        })

}
```