# ios SWIFT found nil while unwrapping option value.

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

After doing some research and asking other question on stack i can not seem to figure out the issue. Yet i have come far.

I am new to Stack so please let me know if i need to provide more information.

The error is appering at

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Saying in the compiler

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Option Value
>   IIDB

if i delete that line the error appears on a another .mapView. line.

When i move the line where the error appear, and put it under:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
```

The app opens and everything works fine, except it dont show the location, but i am able to run the app without getting any error.

Thank you for your time.

Here is my codes if someone need it.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import CoreLocation
import MapKit  


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: mapview.delegate == nil? if yes, then set it in storyboard

Comment: I am very ew, how do i do this?

Comment: Select storyboard->select mapview->show the connections inspector->drag + sigh to the mapview's vc

Comment: Yes it is a referencing Outlets from mapView - View controller, and it is no spelling mistakes

Comment: try to quit and reopen Xcode

Comment: Still dont work. Is it another way to connect map instead of CTR and drag?

Comment: can you debug and look for your mapview outlet?just check for it, if it's nil in viewDidLoad

Comment: I am not sure how you do it. But in the compiler/debugger it says: Mapview =(MKMapView!) nil. Everyother there got some code like "0x00007....

Comment: so, your mapView is nil.maybe try to clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: "mapView.showUserLocation = true" returns "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707991/swift-mapview-showuserlocation-true-returns-fatal-error-unexpectedly-foun)

Answer (score 2):

The only reason why it would be returning a found nil error on a property would be because the property had not yet been instantiated. Given that you're using an IBOutlet, I imagine that you haven't hooked the property to the map view in your storyboard.

See [Swift: "mapView.showUserLocation = true" returns "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707991/swift-mapview-showuserlocation-true-returns-fatal-error-unexpectedly-foun?rq=1) for more info.

Comment: So i am not supposed to CTR and drag? I am very new to xcode so i do not understand another way to set the map as property using @IBoutlet

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `locationManager.requestLocation()` instead of `self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true`

Check if your info.plist contains 'Privacy - Location Usage Description'